# How to extract single column with Spring FixedLengthTokenizer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In all examples ranges are looking similar to something below and they are supposed to extract multiple colums.

```
<bean id="fixedFileTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
        <property name="names" value="Producto , Localidad, Moneda, Comp_instit, Saldo, Filler" />
        <property name="columns" value="1-3, 4-9, 10-12, 13-15, 16-29, 30-31" />
</bean>
```

But how should I extract data from single column? Putting just `16` does not work. Should it be something like `16-16` or `16-17`?

Comment: Single column == Column with one character. As for trying this out I have just ran batch job with 16-16, but it will take a while before completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I have found out that correct range to extract single character is `16-16`.